# How to check mod_ssl.so version?

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl

I'm running `Apache 2.2.3` and would like to find out, how to check version of `mod_ssl.so` and if this module can support `TLSv1.1` and `TLSv1.2`.

Answer (score 5):

A way to do this on a linux/unix system:

```
# strings mod_ssl.so | egrep '^mod_ssl\/|^OpenSSL '
```

- mod_ssl/2.2.6
- OpenSSL 0.9.8f 11 Oct 2007

Answer (score 0):

```
grep TLSv1.2 /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
```

Comment: Thank You. Do you know how I can update mod_ssl.so?Is it only by updating Apache?

Comment: Yes. That lib is part of Apache. On some distros it could be a separate package but nevertheless if you upgrade Apache it should also update that lib.

Comment: In order to get newer version of mod_ssl.so, I have compiled and installed Apache 2.2.29 (in different location) from source and then replaced mod_ssl.so on Apache 2.2.3. Looks that mod_ssl.so from Apache 2.2.29 does not support TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2. Do you think this is sufficient verification and I can say that Apache 2.2.29 does not support TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2?